# Haskell Expected type: IO Char Actual type: String

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Here's my code:

```
    mingle :: String -> String -> String
    mingle (a:as) (b:bs) = ([a] ++ [b]) ++ mingle as bs
    mingle [] [] = []
    main = putStrLn "Enter 1st String:"
                >> getLine
                >>= \a -> read a >> putStrLn "Enter 2nd String:"
                >> getLine
                >>= \b -> read b >>= mingle a b
```

Error:

```
MingleStrings.hs:10:45:
    Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
    Expected type: IO Char
      Actual type: String
    In the second argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘mingle a b’
    In the expression: read b >> mingle a b
```

I was under the impression that read would be able to turn an IO type to a standard haskell type. None of the other posts about dealing with IO seemed to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` doesn't return `IO` type as evidenced by it's type signature:

```
λ> :t read
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

What you want to do is this:

```
main = putStrLn "Enter 1st String:"
       >> getLine
       >>= \a -> putStrLn "Enter 2nd String:"
       >> getLine
       >>= \b -> return $ mingle a b
```

Since `mingle` is a pure function, you have to use `return` to inject `IO` on top of that. Also note that your `mingle` function doesn't handle all the cases. So you may want to fix that.

Comment: So I read that main is an IO type or something like that and so it must return something of IO? I was given that the string lengths will be the same.

Comment: @jchen114 Yes `main` should return something of `IO` type.